# calculating amount based on uneven ranges in C

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, stdio

I was going through previous paper questions and found a question that requires me to produce a bill based on the number of units(of electricity) each customer have consumed. there's a table given instructing how the calculation is done. I already made the program in a very basic way using if else statements. I want to know if there is a better approach to this than using if else. maybe loops ? I tried using loops but its impractical to me since the ranges are not constant. 
This is a screenshot of a portion of that question.[Question Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvd6S.png)

The function I created to calculate is given below.

```
void findBill(int table[],float ar[],int size)
{
int i; 
float bill;
for(i=0; i<7 ; i++)
{
    if((table[i]>=0)&&(table[i]<=5))
    {   bill=table[i]*3.0;
    }
    else if((table[i]>=6)&&(table[i]<=10))
    {   bill=5*3.0+(table[i]-5)*7.0;
    }
    else if((table[i]>=11)&&(table[i]<=15))
    {   bill=5*3.0+5*7.0+(table[i]-10)*15.0;
    }
    else if((table[i]>=16)&&(table[i]<=20))
    {   bill=5*3.0+5*7.0+5*15.0+(table[i]-15)*30.0;
    }
    else if((table[i]>=21)&&(table[i]<=25))
    {   bill=5*3.0+5*7.0+5*15.0+5*30.0+(table[i]-20)*50.0;
    }
    else if((table[i]>=26)&&(table[i]<=30))
    {   bill=5*3.0+5*7.0+5*15.0+5*30.0+5*50.0+(table[i]-25)*75.0;
    }
    else if((table[i]>=31)&&(table[i]<=40))
    {   bill=5*3.0+5*7.0+5*15.0+5*30.0+5*50.0+5*75.0+(table[i]-30)*90.0;
    }
    else if((table[i]>=41)&&(table[i]<=50))
    {   bill=5*3.0+5*7.0+5*15.0+5*30.0+5*50.0+5*75.0+10*90.0+(table[i]-40)*105.0;
    }
    else if((table[i]>=51)&&(table[i]<=75))
    {   bill=5*3.0+5*7.0+5*15.0+5*30.0+5*50.0+5*75.0+10*90.0+10*105.0+(table[i]-50)*110.0;
    }
    else if(table[i]>75)
    {   bill=5*3.0+5*7.0+5*15.0+5*30.0+5*50.0+5*75.0+10*90.0+10*105.0+25*110.0+(table[i]-75)*120.0;
    }

    ar[i]=bill; 
}
```

}

Even though this works i feel that this is bad coding, what if there were 100 ranges. Please suggest me another easier way to do this rather than writing simple if else statements.

P.S : I am a beginner, so please be kind enough to suggest answers using stdio.h in C.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Hashmap is one option. Also, is there a reason to have `5*3.0+5*7.0` and the like everywhere? This is a constant... You can simplify this kind of thing to `50.0`. If this were production code, I'd probably put this in an external file somehow.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider: It sometimes is easier to comprehend to show how the value is calculated. But I agree using magic numbers is a very bad idea and error prone.

Comment: You are asked to pass the *size of the array* as a parameter and you did it, but then you hard-coded `7` in your code. It should be `size`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no fixed pattern for the calculation of the costs depending on the number of the units it is difficult to avoid the hardcoded array of the values.

But the implementation you made can be much cleaner i think.

The approach that i think is better is the following

```
void findBill(int table[], float arr[], int size) {

    int levels[]={75,50,40,30,25,20,15,10,5,0};
    float costs[]={120,110,105,90,75,50,30,15,7,3};
    int level_cnt=sizeof(levels) / sizeof(int);

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        arr[i]=0;
        for(int c=0;c<level_cnt;c++) {
            if(table[i]>levels[c]) {
                arr[i]+=(table[i]-levels[c])*costs[c];
                table[i]=levels[c];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little program that is more expandable than your current example. It uses loops, so it has a O(n) time and space complexity, where as your program has constant complexity for both. Despite this, my code would calculate the values for any size range filled with any values. This code does require you to actually hardcode in the ranges, but that's relatively easy to get rid of.

```
int calcBill(int input){
        int total = 0;
        int billCost[] = {3,7,15,30,50,75,90,105,110,120};
        int billRange[] = {5,10,15,20,25,30,40,50,75,200};
        int rangeAdd[10];
        int sizeOfRange = sizeof(billCost)/sizeof(int);
        //add up the first section
        int i = 0;
        for(; i<sizeOfRange; i++){
                if(i == 0)
                        rangeAdd[i] = billCost[i] * billRange[i];
                else {
                        rangeAdd[i] = billCost[i] * (billRange[i] - billRange[i-1]);
                        rangeAdd[i] += rangeAdd[i-1];
                }
        }
        i = 0;
        for(; i<sizeOfRange; i++){
                if(billRange[i] > input)
                        break;
        }
        if(i == 0){
                total = input * billCost[0];
        }
        else {
                total += (input - billRange[i-1]) * billCost[i];
                if(i > 0)
                        total += rangeAdd[i-1];
        }
        printf("%d %d\n", input, total);
        return total;
}
```

This code uses two arrays (billCost and billRange) to calculate how much each bill costs when you use all units in a given range. For instance, the bill for 25 units is stored at index 4 in the rangeAdd array, the bill for 30 units is stored at index 5. This is pretty easy to calculate just looping over both arrays. The code then finds the index of the maximum range in which your units fall for both arrays (for an input of 36, that would be the range 31-40, or index 7). The code calculates the number of units in that range, and adds the total bill for that range (Units * price) to the precalculated value held in the rangeAdd value for the index directly below it.

Obviously, if you run this program hundreds of times, the rangeAdd array in this function will be recalculated each time. You could precalculate this and pass it in to the function as a variable. This is simply a proof of concept, and can be made much more efficient.

Answer (score -1):

You were thinking of something like this?  The code is fairly simple to follow.  Feel free to ask questions if needed.

```
#include <limits.h> // MAX_INT
#define MIN(a, b) {((a) < (b)) ?  (a) : (b);

typedef struct RATE_DEF
{
    float slice;    // ceiling for this rate - ceiling fro previous rate
    float ppu;      // price per unit
};


const struct RATE_DEF RATE_TABLE[] = 
{
    { 5,   3.f },
    { 5,   7.f },
        /* ... */
    { MAX_INT, 120.f },  // much better
};

#define NUM_RATES (sizeof(RATE_TABLE) / sizeof(RATE_TABLE[0]))

void findBill(int table[],float ar[],int size)
{
int i, j, amt, slice; 
float bill;
for(i=0; i<7 ; i++)
{
    amt = table[i];
    bill = 0.f;

    for (j = 0; amt > 0 && j < NUM_RATES; ++j)
    {
        slice = MIN(amnt, RATE_TABLE[j].slice);
        bill += (slice * RATE_TABLE[j].ppu);
        amt -= slice;
    }

    ar[i] = bill; 
}
```

[EDIT] there are a couple of typos, but I feel lazy today :)